# Easy regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

This pertains to a regex expression.If I have a document with the word Chapter in it how could I select the space right before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\s+(?=Chapter)
```

should do it.  `\s+` matches space, and `(?=Chapter)` matches the zero-length string that is followed by the word "Chapter".

For .net, space is defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx thus:

> `\s` Matches any white-space character. Equivalent to the Unicode character classes `[\f\n\r\t\v\x85\p{Z}]`. If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified with the ECMAScript option, `\s` is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v]` (note leading space).